# How can I get the vendors chunk names of an async chunk with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, html-webpack-plugin, code-splitting, splitchunksplugin

Let's say I have 3 async chunks that were created by dynamic imports:

```
const Notes = lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "notes" */ 'pages/Notes'))
const Lists = lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "lists" */ 'pages/Lists'))
const Files = lazy(() => import(/* webpackChunkName: "files" */ 'pages/Files'))
```

Will generate:

```
notes.g3g43g.js
lists.534535.js
files.234f8t.js
```

Each of these chunks contains it's own vendor dependencies.

So inside *notes.g3g43g.js* we have *react-big-calendar* and *lodash*.

However, when using SplitChunksPlugin, we can set the *chunks* option to *all*:

```
optimization: {
  runtimeChunk: 'single',
  splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all',
    cacheGroups: {
      vendor: {
        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
        name: ({ context }) => (context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From this point, *react-big-calendar* and *lodash* might be split into their own seperate vendor chunks (so they can be used by other async chunks aswell), sometimes the chunk name will be the same as the package name, but other times it can just be the id of the entry point (like *466*).

My question is: how can I tell what are the async vendor chunks of *notes.g3g43g.js*?

I've been looking into the *compilation* object emitted to *HtmlWebpackPlugin* but could not find anything that will point me to what *notes* chunk depends on:

```
new HtmlPlugin({
  filename: `${name}.html`,
  scriptLoading: 'module',
  templateContent: ({ compilation }) => {
    console.log(compilation)
  }
})
```

Any ideas how can I find out?

**Disclaimer**: What I attempt to do is generating multiple html documents (one for each route) and then inlining a preload of all their relevent scripts in the document.

*notes.html*:

```
<head>
  <script type="module" src="js/runtime.dc0c50.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="js/%40emotion.16b5a2.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="js/react-dom.db73d8.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="js/main.f337ee.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <link rel="preload" href="js/notes.g3g43g.js" as="script">
  <link rel="preload" href="js/react-big-calendar.35994c.js" as="script">
  <link rel="preload" href="js/466.f9ej43.js" as="script">

  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

This will prevent additional roundtrips to the CDN, since every chunk already has all of it's dependencies.